# Looping over Structures and storing result in a variable using ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, structure

I have a structure in ColdFusion

```
<cfscript>
paramMap = structNew("Ordered");
/** Create a structure and set its contents. **/
paramMap['hashKey'] = "HM53BC0C176Z58PV";
paramMap['storeId'] = "3528";
paramMap['amount']="30";
paramMap['postBackURL']="http://shopweb.windsorparking.com/php/getToken.php";
paramMap['orderRefNum']="1008";
paramMap['expiryDate']="20190721 112300";
paramMap['autoRedirect']=0;
paramMap['paymentMethod']='MA_PAYMENT_METHOD';
paramMap['emailAddr']='fakhar.munir88@gmail.com';
paramMap['mobileNum']="03345400644";
 /** Build a table to display the contents **/

</cfscript>
```

How to I store it into a a single variable like a querystring like
input=amount=30.0&autoRedirect=0&emailAddr=fakhar.munir88@gmail.com&expiryDate=20190721 112300&mobileNum=03345400644&orderRefNum=1008&paymentMethod=MA_PAYMENT_METHOD&postBackURL=http://shopweb.windsorparking.com/cf/getToken.cfm&storeId=3528

Comment: @jontro the question is the same. The accepted answer in that question does not result in the string the question asks for. The 2nd answer is right, though.

Comment: Why don't you simply build your variable using string or list functions at the same time you are populating your structure?

Comment: @BernhardDöbler it's the same question as the OP have and as you say there is one answer that's right. Doesn't matter if it's the accepted one

Comment: Thanks Guys for helping me out... I couldn't find the right answer